# Boxing & Unboxing: Why doesn't this delegate match?

Tags: c#, boxing, anonymous-methods, unboxing

Assuming the following delegate "caller" signature:

```
FuncCaller<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

and a matching method:

```
bool MyFunc(object o)
```

When `T` is a reference type, I can invoke `MyFunc` *implicitly* like so:

```
FuncCaller<String>(MyFunc) // valid
```

Conversely, when `T` is a value type, I get a compilation error when calling MyFunc implicitly:

```
FuncCaller<Int32>(MyFunc) // invalid ("No overload for 'MyFunc(object)' matches delegate 'System.Func<int?,bool>'")
```

My question is, given these two examples, why is the call to `MyFunc` invalid when invoked implicitly, but valid when invoked *explicitly* like so:

```
FuncCaller<Int32>(i => MyFunc(i)) // valid
```

I assume this is some kind of issue related to boxing and unboxing of types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what it is.

```
FuncCaller<Int32>(i => MyFunc(i)) // valid
```

creates an anonymous function, with a parameter of type `Int32`, and a return value of `bool`, which does nothing but convert the parameter to `object`, and calls `MyFunc`. It's as if you'd written

```
FuncCaller<Int32>(MyFunc2)
```

where `MyFunc2` is defined as

```
bool MyFunc2(Int32 o) { return MyFunc(o); }
```

Converting the parameter is a no-op and therefore unnecessary when the type is a reference type, which is why a function with a parameter type of `object` is close enough for a delegate with a parameter type of `string`: the parameter type is *already* an `object`.

Converting the parameter is a real operation that cannot be bypassed when the type is a value type.

It's worth pointing out that

```
FuncCaller<Int32>(MyFunc)
```

isn't ever shorthand for

```
FuncCaller<Int32>(i => MyFunc(i))
```

even though it may behave almost the same way. The former passes the `MyFunc` function directly, the latter creates a wrapper function around it. That wrapper function is necessary here.